# how to deal with array ComplexType in NuSoap?

Tags: php, web-services, nusoap, complextype

currently i am using PHP Version 5.4.16, and NuSoap 0.95, i have try this example :
[here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3arJV7zjQidHQJ%3awww.nonplus.net/geek/000752.php%20create%20complex%20type%20in%20xml%20using%20nusoap%20web%20services%20with%20nested%20array%20in&client=firefox-a&hs=L5i&hl=en&gl=in&strip=0)

which shown the server code like this ;

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'Chapter',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    'all',
    '',
    array(
        'title' => array('name'=>'title','type'=>'xsd:string'),
        'page' => array('name'=>'page','type'=>'xsd:int')
    )
);

$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'ChapterArray',
    'complexType',
    'array',
    '',
    'SOAP-ENC:Array',
    array(),
    array(
        array('ref'=>'SOAP-ENC:arrayType','wsdl:arrayType'=>'tns:Chapter[]')
    ),
    'tns:Chapter'
);

$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'Book',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    'all',
    '',
    array(
        'author' => array('name'=>'author','type'=>'xsd:string'),
        'title' => array('name'=>'title','type'=>'xsd:string'),
        'numpages' => array('name'=>'numpages','type'=>'xsd:int'),
        'toc' => array('name'=>'toc','type'=>'tns:ChapterArray')
    )
);

$server->register(
    'getBook',
    array('title'=>'xsd:string'),
    array('return'=>'tns:Book'),
    $NAMESPACE);

function getBook($title) {
     // Create TOC
     $toc = array();
     $toc[] = array('title' => 'Chapter One', 'page' => 1);
     $toc[] = array('title' => 'Chapter Two', 'page' => 30);

     // Create book
     $book = array(
                 'author' => "Jack London",
                 'title' => $title,
                 'numpages' => 42,
                 'toc' => $toc);

     return $book;
}
```

but got error returned at the SOAP Response, i am testing it using SopUI. i got an error like this :

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\lib\nusoap.php</b> on line <b>6132</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\lib\nusoap.php</b> on line <b>6132</b><br />
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:getBookResponse xmlns:ns1="http://localhost/myweb"><return><author>Jack London</author><title>This is my book</title><numpages>42</numpages><toc><item><title>Chapter One</title><page>1</page></item><item><title>Chapter Two</title><page>30</page></item></toc></return></ns1:getBookResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

how can i fix this error? can somebody help me to solve this error please... many thanks in advance...

Comment: Look in nusoap.php at line 6132 to see what it tries to convert to a string. It looks like your sending an array at some place and nusoap is trying to use it as a string.

Answer (score 6):

In `nusoap > lib > nusoap.php`, comment line **6132**:

```
////$this->debug("serializing array element: $k, $v of type: $typeDef[arrayType]");
```

Comment: My error is also fixed but i don't know what was exact problem?

Comment: The problem is if $k, $v, or $typeDef is an array instead of a string.  For me $v was an array.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's resolve problem on array sending to client!

Answer (score 0):

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'Book',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    'all',
    '',
    array(
        'author' => array('name1'=>'author','type'=>'xsd:string'),
        'title' => array('name2'=>'title','type'=>'xsd:string'),
        'numpages' => array('name3'=>'numpages','type'=>'xsd:int'),
        'toc' => array('name4'=>'toc','type'=>'tns:ChapterArray')
    )
);

$server->register(
    'getBook',
    array('title'=>'xsd:string'),
    array('return'=>'xsd:array'),
    $NAMESPACE);
```

Comment: you dont use your complexType here ?

Answer (score 0):

A neater solution than commenting the line `6132` in `nusoap > lib > nusoap.php` would be to check if `$v` is an array and convert it to string:

current line 6132:

`$this->debug("serializing array element: $k, $v of type: $typeDef[arrayType]");`

change to:

```
$this->debug("serializing array element: $k, " . ( is_array($v) ? join(',', $v) : $v ) . " of type: $typeDef[arrayType]");
```